# What license do I need to connect SSRS 2014 to Azure SQL Database

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database, ssrs-2014

I want to create a new VM with SSRS 2014 that will be able to connect to Azure Database. When setting up this VM, what SQL license do I need to choose?

Will I be able to connect with standard or do I need enterprise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is a license issue, you can call Microsoft Licensing at 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist. You can also visit the following site for more information and support on licensing issues:

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/mla/default.aspx

Comment: do we have to pay for this ?

Comment: No. It is free. You can explain them all production scenarios and they will give you a quote or estimation of the licensing costs.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Thanks for this. I was able to call and find out that either standard or enterprise can connect to Azure Database.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for visiting StackOverflow. Have a great weekend!